# Javascript If Button is pressed - do stuff

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking for something like:

```
if (..button1 is pressed..){
some function
}

if (...button2 is pressed...){
some other function
}
```

But all of those need to be a part of some completely different function.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".Test").hover(function () {
  if (...Button is pressed...) {
 $('.dropdown').slideToggle('medium');
  }
});
});
```

Comment: and what's the question

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: you want to know if a button is pressed while hovering over something else? probably not possible, because there's only one cursor

Comment: where you use hover inside check press button is not proper structure.

Comment: Don't mind the hover part. What i am concerned with is how to check if the button is pressed, and then do stuff

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want a to attach event listener to a few buttons? In that case you can do it like the following code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btn1').click(function() {
    // do stuff with button 1
    console.log('button 1 clicked');
  });
  $('#btn2').click(function() {
    // do stuff with button 2
    console.log('button 2 clicked');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='btn1'>button 1</button>
<button id='btn2'>button 2</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing that console log can be displayed in the snippet.

Comment: We are using event listeners, so if statements are not required. You can put your logic in the block that contains the console.log.

Comment: @D-reaper I need to change divs that are showing as i hover over (.test) depending on which button i press. Here is a part of my code: https://codepen.io/coolcake/pen/EXjLEw  If i do it just by assigning stuff to each button, then all of those divs are showing at once. I wonder if there is a way to stop the slideToggle effect, but I think the better way of going around it is having if (..buton1 is pressed.)...

Answer (score 1):

You may use `target` to find clicked button id and store that id on global variable to use in hover.

```
   var id ='';
   $("button").click(function(e){
        id= e.target.id;
    });
```

Later on hover you can use that global variable.

```
$(".Test").hover(function () {
  if (id=='matchYourID') {
    $('.dropdown').slideToggle('medium');
  }
});
```

Comment: If the button is inside `.Test`, the user could click a button, leave the `.Test`, and re-enter it to click another button, and the second time, it would erroneously react based on the first button pressed, and not respond at all the first time due to `id = ''`. Plus global variables aren't a great way to handle this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## Example

```js
$(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(event){
    alert('button 1 clicked');
  });

  $('#button2').click(function(event){
    alert('button 2 clicked');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id='button1'>button 1</button>
    <button id='button2'>button 2</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything that wasn't already covered by the other answer.